# Passing filename as argument causing segmentaion fault when the file is not found

Tags: c, file

I want to open a file by taking the filename as a command-line argument and then passing it to a function.

The code works perfectly fine when the file is opened, but it throws a segmentation fault error message when the file is not found. It also works when I shift the file opening logic from the `runFile` function to `main` function but it is causing segmentation fault when the filename is passed as an argument to the function.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void runFile(char* fileName);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{   
    if (argc != 2)
    {   
        printf("Usage: ./lexer [source]\n");
        exit(64);
    }
    else
    {   
        runFile(argv[1]);
    }
    return 0;
}

void runFile(char* file)
{
    FILE *fp;
    if (!filename)
    {
        printf("Error");
    }

    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if ((fp = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not opened!");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File opened Successfully!\n");
    }



    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: @user786 duh! I dont want to open it. I just want to show a error message "File not opened/Found" when the file doesnt not exist.

Comment: `if (!filename) ...` <<-- filename is not defined.

Comment: @wildplasser that's a typo that occured when i copied a commented out portion of the code as well. The problem was already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your `runFile()` function like this:

```c
void runFile(char* file) {
  FILE* fp = fopen(file, "r");

  if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("File not opened!\n");
    return;
  }

  // do something with the file
  printf("File opened!\n");

  fclose(fp);
}
```

The problem with your code was that you still called `fclose(fp)` even when `fp` was `NULL` (because it could not open the file); `fclose(fp)` should be called only once and only when `fp != NULL`.

Comment: I actually wanted to put an `exit(int)` function right after the `printf("File not opened") line where you put the `return` statement. Thanks for pointing out the issue.

Also I didn't know `fclose()` should only be called when the file is opened. That seems really obvious now. Than You!